# WPF scrollbar not scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf

I have applied a scroll bar in my textbox. It shows the scroll bar but doesn't move text vertically. Where I am doing wrong?

**Code**

```
  <TextBox x:Name="com" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" FontSize="20" IsEnabled="False"   Background="{StaticResource img}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="151" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="1050" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding **ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"** and setting **IsEnabled = True**.